# Can't bind to 'kendoDropDownTreeHierarchyBinding' since it isn't a known property of 'kendo-dropdowntree'

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I am using `kendo-dropdowntree` to implement a down down with tree view. I have imported the component in `app.module.ts` but the error doesn't seem to disappear. What could be the issue?

**app.module.ts**

```js
...
import { DropDownsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
   ...
    DropDownsModule 
   ...
  ]
})
```

**feature.component.html**

```html
<kendo-dropdowntree kendoDropDownTreeExpandable
                              [kendoDropDownTreeHierarchyBinding]="data"
                              [textField]="'text'"
                              [valueField]="'id'"
                              [childrenField]="'items'">
</kendo-dropdowntree>
```

**feature.component.ts**

```js
public data: any[] = [
    {
      text: 'Furniture', id: 1, items: [
        { text: 'Tables & Chairs', id: 2 },
        { text: 'Sofas', id: 3 },
        { text: 'Occasional Furniture', id: 4 }
      ]
    },
    {
      text: 'Decor', id: 5, items: [
        { text: 'Bed Linen', id: 6 },
        { text: 'Carpets', id: 7 }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

Here's the error:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As I tested, it seems like you have to add  `"@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "5.5.0"` to the `package.json` file and do an `npm install` and run. it works.

if you are using older versions of  `"@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "5.5.0"`, then `kendoDropDownTreeHierarchyBinding` didn't worked.